# Salesforce lightning: "TypeError: action.$getComponent$ is not a function" exception around $A.enqueueAction(action);

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

This gave me over 5 hours of brain damage, and yet don't have a solution. Can someone please assist?

UPDATE: markup in component:

```
<td>
    <div class="slds-truncate" >
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.nextStage}">Complete</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

UPDATE: controllerJS function:

```
nextStage: function(component, event, helper){
        console.log("----------------> nextStage 0");
        helper.completeStage(component, event, helper);               
    },
```

helperJS function:

```
completeStage : function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('---------------> completeStage 1 ');
        var action = component.get("c.uselessMethod");

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            console.log('---------------> completeStage 2');
        });

        try{
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
        catch(err3){
            console.log("---------------> completeStage EXCEPTION " + err3);
        }
    },
```

This is my apex controller method:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static void uselessMethod(){
        system.debug(logginglevel.error,'------------------------------------> uselessMethod! ');
    }
```

Browser Console Log:

```
---------------> completeStage 1 
---------------> completeStage EXCEPTION TypeError: action.$getComponent$ is not a function
```

The callback is not being invoked at all. `$A.enqueueAction(action)` is generating an exception. No Apex debug log either. My web search yielded irrelevant results.

Comment: a) Did you map the controller to the component? And b) did you try removing the try-catch?

Comment: a) What do you mean by this? b) Yes. When I remove try-catch, the page will display a pop-up with the same error message upon button click.

Comment: I can't see the entire markup. Do you have `<aura:component controller="xxx">` specified?

Comment: Ah, yes. The apex controller method I posted is a part of it.

Comment: I copy and pasted what you have in your description as a TestComponent and put it in a test app with only the component and it works as expected:

components/c/TestComponent.js:10 ----------------> nextStage 0
components/c/TestComponent.js:16 ---------------> completeStage 1 
components/c/TestComponent.js:20 ---------------> completeStage 2

Comment: is it in a dev org? what release are you on summer 17? is this your complete code or is it part of a bigger code where you are calling multiple server side controllers?

Comment: Do you have an attribute named "action" or "uselessMethod"? I your controller set properly?

Comment: Do you have any function with same name as @auraenabled method. eg:- in given expample do you have any js controller function named useless method?

Comment: Does it help if you wrap the function you pass to action.setCallback() with $A.getCallback()?

Comment: Currently experiencing this as well.
I have encountered it before but forgotten what the resolution was...
Are you also getting any errors around unwinding of the stack?

Comment: Found we were getting this at times with extension component helper methods.
We have a method in a base component that the others extend that handles the server call but finding that sometimes if we extend a component that extends this base component it is causing this error.  doing a direct call seems to resolve the error.  
Without the try/catch we also get an error about unwinding.  It is rather annoying as it was working and then suddenly it stopped working.... not sure if it is to do with the size of the components or what but that is about the only thing I can think of...

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this error might be caused by a variety of issues, but as Tony White mentioned, I was encountering this in a concrete component that extended an abstract component, that extended another abstract component.

I fixed this issue by making sure the API versions of all three components were the same.  The concrete component was set to an API version of 40, where as the other components were API 38 and API 39.  Setting all versions to API 39 resolved it.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I had a similar issue, but the aura framework couldn't find the `$getDef$` method on the action. I had version 39 on the abstract component and 53 on the inherited. Changing the version to 39 on the last one fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the component gets corrupt and starts giving this issue as well. There is no mistake in your code just try calling the same things in a new component and I can assure it will work well.

Comment: Considering adding this to comments rather than answer.